# Redirect after a POST vs redirect after a GET

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring project. Here's my basic controller:

```
@Controller
public class Editor {

private static final String EDITOR_URL = "/editor";

@RequestMapping(value = EDITOR_URL, method = {POST, GET})
public ModelAndView edit(HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, 
        @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {

    // The code is trimmed to keep it short
    // It doesn't really matter where it gets the URL, it works fine
    String redirectURL = getRedirectUrl();
    // redirectURL is going to be /editor/pad.html
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + redirectUrl);
}
```

From web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>edm</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have jetty embedded and I'm trying an integration test:

```
@Test
public void redirectToEditPadSuccess() throws Exception {

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(END_POINT + "/edm/editor")
            .queryParam("param1", "val1")
            .queryParam("param2", "val2");

    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);

    HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            builder.build().encode().toUri(),
            HttpMethod.POST,
            entity,
            String.class);

    HttpHeaders httpResponseHeaders = response.getHeaders();

    List<String> httpReponseLocationHeader = httpResponseHeaders.get("Location");
    assertTrue(httpReponseLocationHeader.size() == 1);

    String redirectLocation = httpReponseLocationHeader.get(0);
    URL redirectURL = new URL(redirectLocation);

    assertEquals("/edm/editor/pad.html", redirectURL.getPath());

}
```

So when I execute the above it works fine and I get a green OK sign.

Now, the controller accepts both POST and GET methods. If I execute the test using GET method (replacing HttpMethod.POST with HttpMethod.GET), the result is going to be a 404.

The logs reveal:

```
WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/edm/editor/pad.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'edm'
```

I tried to debug the application up to the DispatcherServlet and weird thing is that with GET, after the 302/redirect response the Dispatcher is being called again and turns this to a 200 - no idea how and why.

Comment: Not an answer, but the reasonable thing to do would be for edit to always be a POST.

Comment: @NathanHughes If you think of it as an actual document edit you're right - maybe the naming is not the best. However "/editor" is going to get called after a redirection from another service (and it's not going to actually apply any changes/edit anywhere) so it has to be a GET.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try and explain what is going on, and then provide a solution.

First let's forget that you're running a rest case, and assume that the request is coming from a browser.

**Scenario 1 : Browser issues a GET request, and the server responds with a redirect.**

In this case, the browser reads the response status code as `302` and makes another request using the `Location` response header. The user sees a quick reload but doesn't notice anything wrong.

**Scenario 2 : Browser issues a POST request, and the server responds with a redirect.**

In this case, the browser does follow the response code and does issue a redirect, but, the second request is a GET request, and the original request body is lost in the second request. This is because strictly by HTTP standards, the browser cannot "re-post" data to the server, without an explicit request by the user. (Some browsers will prompt the user and ask them if they want to re-post)

Now in your code, `RestTemplate` is using what I presume to be a default `HttpClientFactory`, most likely this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java.

This is how RestTemplate is handling the above two scenarios:

**Scenario 1 : Rest Template issues a GET request, and the server responds with a redirect.** 
Here the Rest Template instance will work exactly as a browser would. That's the reason why two requests are being made, and the second one is looking for `/edm/editor/pad.html`

`Scenario 2 : Rest Template issues a POST request, and the server responds with a redirect.` 
In this case, Rest Template will stop after the first call, because it cannot automatically override your request method and change it to `GET`, and it cannot prompt you for permission, like a browser would.

**Solution**: When creating an instance of `RestTemplate`, pass it an overridden version of the client factory, something like

```
new RestTemplate(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
     protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection conn, String httpMethod) throws IOException { 
       super.prepareConnection(conn, httpMethod);    
       conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
     } 
});
```

This will instruct rest template to stop after the first request.

Sorry for the lengthy answer, but I hope this clarifies things.